# How to the get the strings in openRefine that ends with

Tags: python, jython, openrefine

I had 7 strings

```
www.google.com/xx/xx/index.html 
www.google.com/xx/xx/test.pdf   
www.google.com/xx/xx/doenload.ppt   
www.google.com/xx/xx/file.txt   
www.google.com/xx/xx/products   
www.google.com/xx/xx/XML    
www.google.com/xx/xx/index.html
```

and i have to get the only these strings

```
o/p:
www.google.com/xx/xx/index.html
www.google.com/xx/xx/products   
www.google.com/xx/xx/XML    
www.google.com/xx/xx/index.html
```

How do i get only these strings and remove the others in openRefine.

Comment: What you've been trying so far? Could you share your code snippets?

Comment: @kosist if(and(not(value.endsWith(".html")),not(value.endsWith("/"))),"",value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1° Transform using `if(or(value.split("/")[-1].contains("index.html"), value.split("/")[-1].contains(".") == false), value, null)`

[image: his]

2° Facet -> Customized facet --> Facet by blank or null

3° Select `true` in the facets.

4° All --> Edit rows --> Remove all matching rows.

Comment: But i am getting only index.html but not products and XML but i want products and xml along with index.html

Comment: Oh? I added a screenshot to my answer, and you can see that XML and product are preserved.

Comment: but if products will be like www.google.com/xx/xx/products then the condition is not working.

Comment: In this case no, but that's not the question you asked. I cannot guess what your real data looks like if you give examples that do not match it.

Comment: Updated answer too.